# Asp Classic - Manter option select apos post na pagina

Tags: html, asp, html-select

Pessoal preciso de uma ajuda.

Eu tenho o seguinte techo do select HTML

```
<select id="lstTransacao" name="lstTransacao">
     <option value="null">Todos</option>
     <option value="1">Confirmados</option>
     <option value="0">Não confirmados</option>
</select>

<input id="btnFiltrarTransacao" type="submit" name="btnSearch" value="Filtrar Transações" class="style_button" onclick="javascript: filtraTransacao();">
```

É uma pagina que faz uma pesquisa.
Acontece que a pagina tem paginação, quando eu clico nos botão de paginação "1", "2", "3", etc. O SELECT volta para o padrão "todos", gostaria de manter caso eu clique em "Não confirmado" ir passando a paginacao e manter o OPTION VALUE="0" por exemplo.

ASP Classic 3.0

Grato.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na alternância da paginação, você precisa informar a cada página o valor que foi selecionado anteriormente no `<select>`. Então você captura o valor que foi enviado no `submit` e compara em cada `<option>`:

```
<%lstTransacao = request("lstTransacao")%>

<select id="lstTransacao" name="lstTransacao">
     <option <%if lstTransacao = "null" then%> selected="selected" <%end if%> value="null">Todos</option>
     <option <%if lstTransacao = "1" then%> selected="selected" <%end if%> value="1">Confirmados</option>
     <option <%if lstTransacao = "0" then%> selected="selected" <%end if%> value="0">Não confirmados</option>
</select>

<input id="btnFiltrarTransacao" type="submit" name="btnSearch" value="Filtrar Transações" class="style_button" onclick="javascript: filtraTransacao();">
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia.
Uma sugestão seria criar uma label apenas pegar o valor dela no postback e trataria o combobox por Jquery...

Está um dica pode ser melhorada.

```
 <div id="mydiv" class="0">   
  <select id="lstTransacao" name="lstTransacao" >
   <option value="null">Todos</option>
   <option value="1">Confirmados</option>
   <option value="0">Não confirmados</option>
  </select>
 </div>
```

---

```
$("body").ready(function () {
  if ($('#mydiv').hasClass('0')) {
  $("#lstTransacao").val('0');        
}});
```